# Magento 2.2: Unable to unserialize value

Tags: magento2.2, setup-upgrade, unserialize

After running

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.0 --no-update
composer update
```

I ran

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

But while running this command I get the following error:

```
Updating modules:
Unable to unserialize value.
[InvalidArgumentException]
Unable to unserialize value.
```

I read that multiple developers had this problem after upgrading to Magento 2.2 and it could be a problem with installed extension, but for me there isn't any entry in the log files of Magento, PHP or MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem with your cache.
Just cleared your magento cache. If you are using any third party cache like Redis, just flush it and try. It will fix this problem.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I ran:
rm -rf <Magento install dir>/var/cache/*
rm -rf <Magento install dir>/var/page_cache/*
rm -rf <Magento install dir>/generated/code/*

And if I want to run php bin/magento cache:clean it returns: There are no commands defined in the "cache" namespace.

Comment: Check you have provided proper permission to the generated and var folders

Comment: I got this error before and I was using Redis cache. When I flush my Redis cache, the error is gone.

Comment: I already ran this command in my Magento dir: find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} \; && find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} \; && chmod u+x bin/magento

Comment: I don't use any Redis cache.

Comment: I keep getting the same error message. The only way I have found to pass through it, is to disable cache completely. I still need to figure out how to re-enable cache.  Any ideas anyone?